# Is Limit and Norm interchangable in Banach Spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space, and $\{x_n \}\subset X$. Does it then hold that
$\lim \|y-x_n\|=\|y-\lim x_n \| $ ?

Comment: If $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, then yes; since $y-x_n$ then converges to $y-x$.

Comment: You are wondering whether the norm is continuous with respect to itself. The answer is trivially affirmative.

Answer (score 2):

First let's recall what it means to say $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ in a Banach space.  It means $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n-x\|=0$.  The first limit is a limit of a sequence of members of the Banach space; the second is a limit of a sequence of non-negative numbers.

Note that $\|A\|=\|(A-B)+B\|\le \|A-B\|+\|B\|$, so that $$\|A\|-\|B\|\le\|A-B\|,$$ and in the same way show that $$\|B\|-\|A\|\le\|A-B\|,$$ so we have
$$
|\, \|A\|-\|B\| \,|\le \|A-B\|.
$$
Hence
$$
|\,\|y-x_n\|-\|y-x\|\,| \le
\|(y-x_n)-(y-x)\| = \|x_n-x\|  \tag 1
$$
Consequently, if the rightmost term in $(1)$ goes to $0$, then so does the leftmost term.